# In a link in php, what does .:/ do

Tags: php, string, web, require

In a link in php, for example, when using `require()`;

What does `.:/` do in `.:/usr/share/php:/apps/php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` is a path delimiter.  It indicates that the include path, in this case, consists of the directories  `.`, `/usr/share/php`, and `/apps/php`.

That is, the current working directory referenced by `.` plus the two other full directory paths `/usr/share/php`, and `/apps/php`

This is common method in Unix-like systems of separating paths.  Dos/Windows may use a `;` for environment variables instead, though not in PHP configurations, which use `:`.

Answer (score 0):

. - is current directory
: - path separator

So the first directory for include path is current directory.

See [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-include-path.php#73692)

Answer (score 0):

When you use require() it takes as parameter path to file and it is like 'path/to/file.php'. '.:/usr/share/php:/apps/php' is a set of include paths where require() search for 'path/to/file.php'. In include path set dot "." means current directory and ":" is a path separator.